# LINQ extensions for sequence comparing

Tags: c#, functional-programming, linq

The desired behavior would be:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void Compare_Value_Identity()
    {
        var source = new[] { 1, 2 };
        var modified = new[] { 2, 3 };

        var (inserted, deleted) = source.Compare(modified);

        CollectionAssert.AreEqual(new[] { 3 }, inserted.ToArray());
        CollectionAssert.AreEqual(new[] { 1 }, deleted.ToArray());
    }
```

And:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void Compare_Id_Identity()
    {
        var source = new[] { (1, "A"), (2, "B"), (3, "C") };
        var modified = new[] { (2, "B"), (3, "D"), (4, "E") };

        var (inserted, updated, deleted) = source.Compare(modified, x => x.Item1);

        CollectionAssert.AreEqual(new[] { (4, "E") }, inserted.ToArray());
        CollectionAssert.AreEqual(new[] { (3, "D") }, updated.ToArray());
        CollectionAssert.AreEqual(new[] { (1, "A") }, deleted.ToArray());
    }
```

Library code is:

```
public static class SequenceChange
{
    public static (IEnumerable<T> Inserted, IEnumerable<T> Deleted) Compare<T>(
        this IEnumerable<T> source, IEnumerable<T> modified) =>
        source.Compare(modified, EqualityComparer<T>.Default);

    public static (IEnumerable<T> Inserted, IEnumerable<T> Deleted) Compare<T>(
        this IEnumerable<T> source, IEnumerable<T> modified, IEqualityComparer<T> comparer) =>
        (modified.Except(source, comparer), source.Except(modified, comparer));

    public static (IEnumerable<T> Inserted, IEnumerable<T> Updated, IEnumerable<T> Deleted) Compare<T, TKey>(
        this IEnumerable<T> source, IEnumerable<T> modified, Func<T, TKey> keySelector) =>
        source.Compare(modified, keySelector, EqualityComparer<T>.Default);

    public static (IEnumerable<T> Inserted, IEnumerable<T> Updated, IEnumerable<T> Deleted) Compare<T, TKey>(
        this IEnumerable<T> source, IEnumerable<T> modified, Func<T, TKey> keySelector, IEqualityComparer<T> comparer) =>
        (modified.ExceptBy(source, keySelector),
        from s in source
        join m in modified on keySelector(s) equals keySelector(m)
        where !comparer.Equals(s, m)
        select m,
        source.ExceptBy(modified, keySelector));
}
```

Comment: where is the method `ExceptBy` from ? Some library ?

Comment: @Disappointed MoreLinq, [issue](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/issues/737)

Comment: not looking what code produces, what is expected result for comparison of `{ (1, "A"), (1, "F") }` and `{ (1, "B"), (1, "D"), (1, "E") }` ? For me that is not clear ...
Code returns confusing results with 6 updated items (!) which is more than the total number of both sequences

Comment: @Disappointed You do not observe id identity, which is supposed to be there by definition. Imagine business model collection to be synced with database. You would reread business models from the db and compare with the provided modified collection using primary key id to match old and new records to calculate necessary syncing operations. There could not be and should not be any key duplication as long as id identity is observed. Do we need a check with an exception? Probably yes.

Comment: Yes, probably validation and exception is needed for cases when user provides non-unique `keySelector`